# How do I find foreign keys in Teradata Viewpoint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, teradata

Just starting out and I learned the `SHOW TABLE [tablename]` query is supposed to show me primary keys and foreign key information. The database I'm reviewing shows all tables having primary keys, but none of them say foreign keys which I'm pretty sure they are supposed to have when I reference a print out of the RS. How do I find out which primary key is really a foreign key in Teradata Viewpoint?

Comment: In a Warehouse you hardly find Foreign Keys physically implemented in the data model, they're only found in the logical model. It's similar for Primary Keys, not all are actually implemented (if you really get PKs on every table it's a bit strange)

Answer (score 0):

Show table will show you foreign keys. I used SQL*Assistant though, not Viewpoint.

```
create table table1
(
col1a integer primary key not null
, col1b varchar(10)
);
create table table2 
(
col2a integer primary key not null references table1
, col2b varchar(10)
);

show table table2
```

## Output:

```
CREATE SET TABLE table2 ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      col2a INTEGER NOT NULL,
      col2b VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC, 
PRIMARY KEY ( col2a ), 
FOREIGN KEY ( col2a ) REFERENCES table1 ( col1a ))
;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @access_granted , but my homework assignment is using Teradata Viewpoint / SQL Scratchpad. I will make note for SQL*Assistant for future reference.

Comment: I don't believe you can drill lower than table level in Viewpoint (so the keys would be table details), and there doesn't seem to be a SQL interface available either. It's mostly GUI to manage space & users.